# PyScripter - cannot configure editor options - "Unable to write to .tmp"

Tags: python, pyscripter

I have PyScripter installed on two machines. One is installed on a Windows 7 machine and works great. Another is installed on a Windows 10 machine and I cannot access the editor options window. I get the following application error:

```
Unable to write to C:\Users\ROCKHO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\PyS2A17.tmp
```

Any idea what may be locking this temp file and also why PyScripter needs access to this file to modify editor options?

thx!

Comment: Additional Information: I *can* edit the given temp file in a text editor. No problems modifying and saving.

Comment: And more additional information: I *can* edit the "Interpreter Editor Options" from within PyScripter just fine. It's only the "Editor Options" that is hanging me up. This is after fresh download and install several times.

Answer (score 0):

Editor Options stores syntax highlighter information to a Temp ini file, so that it can be restored in case the user cancels the dialog.  This is currently using the Windows WritePrivateProfileString function (old and deprecated).  This sounds like either a file access issue or a bug in WritePrivateProfileString unnecessarily requiring elevated rights.

I never came across this issue before, but to be on the safe side I have committed changes that now save the information in memory.  Please download the next version of PyScripter, coming out in a week or so, from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pyscripter/files/ that should resolve the problem you are facing.